# Href keep showing wrong url path

Tags: html, asp.net, href

In html i write as below

```
<link rel="alternate" href="<%= canocalURL %>" hreflang="zh-cn" /><br />
```

the result i get is

```
<link rel="alternate" href="&lt;%= canocalURL %>" hreflang="zh-cn" /><br />
```

but when i remove the "href" it show like this

```
<link rel="alternate" "localhost:700/Rewards/" hreflang="en-vn" /><br />
```

Any idea why it happens like that

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? Or some template engine? If ASP make sure you're not in razor pages (.cshtml), syntax for that is different if so.

Comment: "but when i remove the "href" it show like this" ? So there's "href" in your canocalURL ?

Comment: @Adriani6 its asp.net

Comment: @Jules yes to direct it to url

Comment: @Hunter That's wrong imo, you should have something more like href=<%canocalURL%> without the href in the canocalURL. You really should remove it

Comment: @Jules i already remove it but the result show "&lt;%= canocalURL %>"

Comment: @Hunter Did you put it exactly like that href=<%canocalURL%> ? Looks like &lt; is an ecapsulation problem (it stands for < )

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="alternate" href=<%= canocalURL %> hreflang="zh-cn" /><br />
```

Try this way.

Comment: tried using your way but my html shows error Attribute values must be enclosed in quotation marks. and if i out the quotation marks it will never work

Answer (score 0):

Use Eval as:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="<%= Eval("canocalURL")%>" hreflang="zh-cn" /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Eval in order to make it correctly work :

```
 href="<%= Eval("canocalURL")%>"
```